# Ad module that opens and closes with drawer effect

Tags: javascript

Total coding novice here especially in Java. I am trying to create an ad module for our site that has two states; First, it is a simple bar with a headline. Then when you rollover it, it opens to reveal the whole ad and remains open until you click the close button, the action button or anywhere outside the ad.

I have worked out the basics but would like to add a drawer transition effect (like a drop-down menu) when the ad opens and closes. I think this needs to be in the Java code as that is what initiates the transitions.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/mcnaden/uppznhs1/

```
$('#ad-01').mouseenter(function() {
  $("#ad-02").css('display', 'block');
})
$('#btn-close').click(function() {
  $("#ad-02").css('display', 'none');
})
$('#ad-02').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$('html').click(function() {
  $("#ad-02").css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: This looks more like JavaScript than like Java. Question tag changed to reflect this.

Comment: you mean like this??? http://jsfiddle.net/ahoqcqjv/

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Thanks! That's definitely the right effect. Just need it without the toggle part. The drawer should not close on a further rollover, only close on a click.

Comment: And now I see that I need to sort out one more detail. The action button (#btn-action) and close button (#btn-close) need to start at opacity 0 at the beginning of the transition and end at opacity 1.

Comment: does anyone know and open effect similar to .slideToggle that does not close? I need the action to open like .slideToggle but require a click to close.